# Error trying to use OneLogin OIDC with SpringBoot (error: redirect_uri_mismatch)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, onelogin

I've trying to connect OneLogin OIDC with SpringBoot for days now and I've not been able to yet.

I'm very new with OIDC, so, maybe I missing something basic.

I've followed these instructions in OpenLogin Administration panel:
https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/connect-to-onelogin

Tried the code in (master branch):
https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-java/tree/master/spring-boot-app

And found out that there is a pull request of a few days ago in the same repository, with a very different solution (karson-demo-2019-oct branch):
https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-java/tree/karson-demo-2019-oct/spring-boot-app

But unfortunately, the solution didn't work.

I'm using the same code of karson-demo-2019-oct branch with only some added properties to the YAML file (please, see below)

I'm configuring the redirect URI in the OneLogin Administration panel as `https://localhost:8081/`.
Once I go to `https://localhost:8081/`, click on "click here", the following error appears:

```
oops! something went wrong
error: redirect_uri_mismatch
error_description: redirect_uri did not match any client's registered redirect_uris
state: bi14wv
```

And the URL is something like:

```
https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/auth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8081/login&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=bi14wv
```

If I add `https://localhost:8081/login` (with "login" in the end) to the list of Redirect URI's in the OneLogin Admin panel, the following happens:
When I go to `https://localhost:8081/` and click on "click here", the OneLogin form appears. Then I login with my user, and then the following message appears:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Nov 05 15:32:02 PST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
Unauthorized
```

And the url of this error page is something like:

```
https://localhost:8081/login?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=ZZZZZ
```

As you can see there is a "login" after the specified redirect URI (`https://localhost:8081`), and I think this could be due to the way the [index.html](https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-java/blob/karson-demo-2019-oct/spring-boot-app/src/main/resources/static/index.html) was written in the solution.

Since the OneLogin portal doesn't accept Redirect URI's with http (only https), I needed to add a few more lines to the application.yml in order to enable SSL:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      clientSecret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      accessTokenUri: https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/auth
      tokenName: access_token
      authorizedGrantTypes: authorization_code
      authenticationScheme: form
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      scope: openid,profile,email
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/me

server:
  port : 8081
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: classpath:XXXXXXXXXXXX
    key-store-password: XXXXXXXXXXXX
    key-alias: XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Is this correct?
Could you please, help me find out what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- I am unfamiliar with the demo client you are running, but it looks like you are correct that the redirect_uri in the request generated by the client contains `/login` and you were correct to add this to your list of redirect_uris in the configuration interface
- `https://localhost:8081/login?code=XX` is the correct response from a successful authentication, the problem must lie in the way the client handles the response and what html `/login` expects to render in your app
- OneLogin does support `http` for `localhost` so you shouldn't have to mess with SSL

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same demo client (Java Spring - Authorization Code Flow) provided by OneLogin - https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/samples and getting Unauthorized (401).

Enabled Spring Security DEBUG logs and found unable to obtain Access token.

- Could you please let me if any additional configuration required to obtain access token.

Here is the trace logs:

```
2020-01-14 17:45:00.487 DEBUG 17920 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'

2020-01-14 17:45:00.487 DEBUG 17920 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication

2020-01-14 17:45:00.495 DEBUG 17920 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Retrieving token from https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/token

2020-01-14 17:45:00.498 DEBUG 17920 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Encoding and sending form: {grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[YTAyOTgxYzctNmU4ZC00OTY1LTk2MjItNDc0YjE1YTQ1ZjMwXbQWtr74HMgMIv5K1ygC6xOiZzfO237Hq81l6zQ9JKGsT2xpkwrTrtojNvrirPK-vbQGrpk7ngg_9BQlgkeCnQ], redirect_uri=[http://localhost:8081/login], client_id=[***************], client_secret=[*********************************]}

2020-01-14 17:45:01.089 DEBUG 17920 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token


org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60) [spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]

Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Error requesting access token.
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:145) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:209) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 53 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:123) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport$AccessTokenErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:246) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:785) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:743) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:698) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```